# About Revealing module pattern in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I'm currently building a mobile web application with jQM, Highcharts and HTML5.

To maintain the JavaScript code, I decided to apply Revealing module pattern to the code.

Here is my code.

```
var MobileWebV1 = function () {

    function _buildPanelMenu(pageId, isNormalMenu) {
    }

    function _buildHeaderBar(pageId, isNormalMenu) {
    }

    return {
        buildPanelMenu: _buildPanelMenu,
        buildHeaderBar: _buildHeaderBar
    };
}();
```

I'm wondering if I can add another hierarchy to categorize methods in the object.

I want to add **'UserInterface'** and '**Util.'** In that case, I can call the method like this: **MobileWebV1.UserInterface.buildPanelMenu('pageHome', false);**

I tried to modify my objecy, but I'm still stuck with the current issue.

If you know the answer, then please share your knowledge.

Comment: Show us what you have tried. Yes, you will need to modify your object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just nest the [object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals):

```
return {
    Util: {
        …
    },
    UserInterface: {
        buildPanelMenu: _buildPanelMenu,
        buildHeaderBar: _buildHeaderBar
    }
};
```